# Variable 'camera' is never used and Casting 'this' to 'LifecycleOwner' is redundant

Tags: android, android-studio

I do not know what I did wrong. Everything seems right except the last couple code. I even tried this

> Camera camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(lifecycleOwner,
> cameraSelector, preview);

And it still does not work. What am I doing wrong? I am trying use CameraX to scan Qr code. Thank you!

```
 private void bindCameraPreview(@NonNull ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider) {
    previewView.setImplementationMode(PreviewView.ImplementationMode.PERFORMANCE);

    Preview preview = new Preview.Builder()
            .build();

    CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
            .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
            .build();

    preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.getSurfaceProvider());

    ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis =
            new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                    .setTargetResolution(new Size(1280, 720))
                    .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                    .build();

    imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), new QRCodeAnalyzer(new QRCodeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onQRCodeFound(String _qrCode) {
            qrCode = _qrCode;
            mAddCamera.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void qrCodeNotFound() {
            mAddCamera.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }));

    Camera camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner)this, cameraSelector, preview);
}
```

Comment: Save it in a global variable . u probably have to use it later in execution . Right now its a local variable that's why u r getting the warning .

Comment: how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In google' s sample code, they unbind before bindToLifecycle, and bind in a try-catch:

```
        cameraProvider.unbindAll() // unbind the use-cases before rebinding them

        try {
            // Bind all use cases to the camera with lifecycle
            cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                this, // current lifecycle owner
                lensFacing, // either front or back facing
                preview, // camera preview use case
                imageCapture // image capture use case
            )
            // Attach the viewfinder's surface provider to preview use case
            preview?.setSurfaceProvider(binding.previewView.surfaceProvider)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG_CAMERA, "Failed to bind use cases", e)
        }
```

Maybe you can find something in the exception.